# submiting HTML form

Tags: php, html

working a little bit with forms in HTML. using the POST method,
but im a little confused about the way the url should look.
i have a process.php file in the libraray with all my other website pages.
im not sure if the usrl should be:
 "http://localhost/process.php" or just "process.php".

what is the difference between them ? 
when im trying the first one im getting this page:
"Not Found

The requested URL /process.php was not found on this server."

and when im trying the other one im getting this page :

`ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

and i have installed wamp...

thank you

Comment: Where in the folder structure does `process.php` live

Answer (score 0):

*localhost/process.php* will look for a file named *process.php* in the root directory of your server (you can change the root directory in the httpd.conf file). The root directory is where your *index.html* or *index.php* is. Linking it to just "process.php" will search for the file in the same working directory as the HTML/PHP file it is being linked from.

Provide code for a more detailed answer.

Comment: If both are in the same place, then yes that should happen. Try the following: Type localhost into the browser and check if the server root is where you think it is, then try localhost/process.php and tell me if it is opening. Post the HTML Page code too.

Comment: im not sure what you mean by "type localhost in the browser".
 but the  localhost/process.php is still getting to the "not found url".@lagboy

Comment: Check your server root in httpd.conf

Comment: is that "/usr/local/apache2" possible serverRoot ? @lagboy

Comment: Could be, go to apache/conf/httpd.conf and check :)

Comment: i found the httpd.conf but it includes more than one "serverRoot" so im confused... i got two possible adresses :
"with ServerRoot set to "/usr/local/apache2" will be interpreted by the" (1)
"same ServerRoot for multiple httpd daemons, you will need to change at
# least PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "E:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9"
 
these two quotes are from the httpd.conf 
which one is it ? @lagboy

Comment: Don't change anything preceded by a "#" and don't remove the "#"